# Very Strange USB Issue

Tags: windows-7, linux, windows-8, usb, mouse

So, I'm using Xubuntu 13.04 (Raring), and I'm having a very strange USB issue.  From time to time, I am experiencing hard system locking any time the mouse -MOVES-.   When the mouse is stationary, the system is normal.

Upon experimentation, I've also figured out that it happens with my X360 controller (when the problem is going on).  Moving an analog stick causes system hanging, but buttons do not.

Also, while this mess is going on, my keyboard works normally.

ALSO, this problem occurs in Windows as well (Win7 and Win8, both, I have a Win8/Xubuntu dualboot right now).

Anyway, this is the section of the dmesg log (from Xubuntu) that happens when the issue is going on (mouse movement while USB is going nuts).

[image]

Comment: The error from dmesg relates to your hard disk controller's SATA channels, not to USB; in general, given that the problem happens across OSes and across USB devices, I'd say the likeliest possibility is that your motherboard's USB controller is suffering some bogosity. You could try a PCI or PCIe USB interface, which will have its own controller, and see if that clears up the problem; if so, it's definitely the motherboard USB controller. A BIOS update might possibly help; failing that, replace the motherboard.

Comment: What is the make and model of your computer and or motherboard? Is this a laptop or a desktop computer? As Aaron mentioned those errors relate to your hard disk,have you ruled out a failing disk?

Comment: The motherboard is an ASUS M4A89GTD PRO w/ USB3.   Desktop PC.